# Java double and Oracle float into SQL Server numeric

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, sqldatatypes

I'm working on a SQL Server database and need to make sure the numeric types are large enough for the data.

There are two sources: Java `double` and Oracle `float(126)`.

The SQL Server types are either `numeric(30,10)` or `numeric(15,8)`.

I read that Java doubles can store values from -4.9E-324 to 1.7976931348623157E+308, Oracle `float(126)` has approximately 38 digits of precision, while SQL Server `numeric(30,10)` has only 30 digits of precision and allows 10 digits after the decimal point.

Am I correct in saying that `numeric(30,10)` is not safe for `double` and `float(126)` and could lead to loss of precision or overflow. Should these be changed to `DOUBLE PRECISION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL's `NUMERIC` is a *decimal* type. `DOUBLE PRECISION` is a binary float type, typically mapped to IEEE 754 douple precision (64 bits), which is exactly the format used by Java's `double`, so that should be a perfect match. `FLOAT` is also a binary type present in the SQL standard, so it should also be present on SQL Server, but its maximum precision is implementation dependant, and if it's smaller on SQL Server there isn't really anything you can do.

Comment: According the the [microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx), the highest value that can be set is 1.79E+308, matching the OPs requirement. Oddly, the lower bounds seem to disagree, which I wouldn't have expected.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : that's the range of a 64 bit float. If Oracle allows FLOAT(126), its range must be a lot bigger. The lower bounds differ because one lists the smallest "regular" value and the other the smallest denormalized one.